# Visual Studio Can't Find <img> Src Path When Hovering Over Link

Tags: html, visual-studio, razor

I've searched but couldn't find anything with this exact question. The screenshot shows what I'm talking about, unfortunately the screenshot tool doesn't capture the popup that comes up but everyone should know what popup that is.

When you hover over an image source link it will display a preview of that image. Well no matter what link to any image I hover over, I get the "No Image Available: Couldn't locate path" error. Yet every image works and displays. I also navigate to the exact path and the images are there. Does anyone know why this can occur?

[image: Image Source Path]

Answer (score 1):

[Url in Razor](http://benjii.me/2015/05/get-the-absolute-uri-from-asp-net-mvc-content-or-action/)

> ```
> @Url.Content("~/images/cuopun.png")
> ```

```
<img src="@(Url.Content("~/images/cuopun.png"))" />
```

Or

> ```
> @Route.AbsolutePath("/images/cuopun.png")
> ```

```
<img src="@(Route.AbsolutePath("/images/cuopun.png"))" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I did add that in and have built and ran it. Image shows up still like before. But it's still showing image not found, couldn't locate [path].

Comment: Ok. What's strange is that I'm getting no intellisense for `@Url` or `@Route`, actually `@Route` says that it does not exist in the current context. I'm still learning so I could be missing something though all other Razor works fine. Does this seem like it could be a Razor issue?